# Multiple Regression Model For Multiple Categories

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, categorical-data

As an example, let's say I want to create a model that predicts what fraction of a population wears gloves (Don't put much logic into the data here, I'm just trying to give an example). I have the following data:

- Fraction of population wearing gloves
- Temperature (Assume I only have data at three temperatures: 5, 10, and 15 Fahrenheit)
- Windspeed
- Relative Humidity

Let's say that the percentage of people wearing gloves can be modeled using a simple linear fit dependent upon temperature. That is, at colder temperatures, more people wear gloves.

However, upon looking more closely at the data set, it also becomes clear that I can separate the observations into two categories based on the temperature and make each category dependent on a different second variable: Cold Days (days when the temperature is below 15F, so either 5 or 10) and Warm Days (days when the temperature is 15F and above).

On cold days, the percentage of glove wearers is dependent on the windspeed, and on warm days, the percentage of glove wearers is dependent on the relative humidity.

Now I know I can create two separate linear fits for the two different categories. The problem with this approach is that by turning temperature simply into a category, we lose the scaling dependence of temperature. For example, on a day when its 60F the number of people wearing gloves would be the same as the number of people wearing gloves when its 25F as long as the relative humidity is the same on both days. Obviously this is absurd, and it underscores the need for a model dependent upon temperature.

Furthermore, by separating the data into two categories, we can see that I only have ONE datapoint for warm days (25F). If I want to make my model dependent upon temperature, I'd need to include the other two temperatures from cold days as well.

So in summary: I was wondering if its possible to create a single model that accounts for the linear dependence on temperature across all temperatures but also includes the effect of windspeed at cold temperatures and relative humidity for warm temperatures.

Is this possible?